# Aggregating on null rows on R

Tags: r

The following is the sample of the data that I'm working on

```
Manager  Exp.in.ED  Count.in.ED  Exp.in.NPA  Count.in.NPA
A           12          1          N/A          N/A
B           14          2          N/A          N/A
C           12          1          N/A          N/A
A           43          3          N/A          N/A
B           12          1          N/A          N/A
C           54          4          N/A          N/A
B           23          1          N/A          N/A
A           15          3          N/A          N/A
```

So as of this data `Exp.in.NPA` and `Count.in.NPA` are null columns. Hence when I'm trying to aggregate them using the following code

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
NPA_exp <- aggregate(data$Exp.in.NPA ~ data$Manager,
                     FUN = sum, na.action = na.pass, na.rm = TRUE)
```

In the console it is showing

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

and the output is giving some non-null values whereas the desired output is an N/A corresponding to each `Manager`.

However when I'm running the same code for `Exp.in.ED` it is giving the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `N/A` which are read as `character` (to be exact as `factor` with the default of `read.csv`). They need to be converted to `NA`.

This can be done with, for instance,

```
data <- data.table::fread("Manager  Exp.in.ED  Count.in.ED  Exp.in.NPA  Count.in.NPA
 A           12          1          N/A          N/A
 B           14          2          N/A          N/A
 C           12          1          N/A          N/A
 A           43          3          N/A          N/A
 B           12          1          N/A          N/A
 C           54          4          N/A          N/A
 B           23          1          N/A          N/A
 A           15          3          N/A          N/A", 
na.strings = "N/A")

print(data)
   Manager Exp.in.ED Count.in.ED Exp.in.NPA Count.in.NPA
1:       A        12           1         NA           NA
2:       B        14           2         NA           NA
3:       C        12           1         NA           NA
4:       A        43           3         NA           NA
5:       B        12           1         NA           NA
6:       C        54           4         NA           NA
7:       B        23           1         NA           NA
8:       A        15           3         NA           NA
```

Now both aggregations do work:

```
aggregate(data$Exp.in.NPA ~ data$Manager,
          FUN = sum, na.action = na.pass, na.rm = TRUE)
  data$Manager data$Exp.in.NPA
1            A               0
2            B               0
3            C               0

aggregate(data$Exp.in.ED ~ data$Manager,
          FUN = sum, na.action = na.pass, na.rm = TRUE)
  data$Manager data$Exp.in.ED
1            A             70
2            B             49
3            C             66
```